# How to add the GridView Cells data into a two dimensional list and retrieve it

Tags: list, gridview, collections, multidimensional-array

I'm iterating through the GridView rows and cells to get the values and store them in a `2D array`.
This is my code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < (GridView2.Rows[i].Cells.Count - 3); j++)
     {
         // using the labels of the template fields.....
         Label values = (Label)GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].FindControl("Label" + j);
         GridValues[i,j] = values.Text; // gridvalues is my 2d array.    
     }
 }
```

What I need now is to make the same values I got from the above loop to be added to a list(2D). So I created a class of that list

This is the code:

```
public  class GridValuesClass
{
    public string GridCustomerName { get; set; }
    public string GridPickUpPoint { get; set; }
    public DateTime GridPickUpDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan GridDropPoint { get; set; }
    public DateTime GridDropDate { get; set; }
    public string GridCabStatus { get; set; }
    public string GridAssignedCab { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan GridActualDropTime { get; set; }
}
```

These properties represent the column names in the gridview.

So, how can I add the values in the gridview inside this class?

And how can I retrieve the values if my values are present in the `list<GridValuesClass>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store it in a 2D array to be later stored in a list. Instead you can store it directly in to the list.

Sort of like this:

```
var list = new List<GridValuesClass>();

for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     var job = new GridValuesClass {
          GridPickUpPoint = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0]...,
          GridPickUpDate = ...,
          // and so on with possible use of conversions to get the correct types
     }
     list.Add(job);
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

As a side note, use more *meaningful* names.

- Give the class a more meaningful class name than `GridValuesClass`, if you have several grid views then this name becomes useless. From what I gather on how you named the properties, it looks more like a job order for cabs. So maybe `JobOrder`?
- `GridView2` tells us nothing. What kind of data does the gridview contain? Perhaps `JobsGridView`?
- Is it necessary to prefix all the fields with `Grid`? What if the data is stored or used in a context where there is no grid view?